# CSV file with quoted comma can't be correctly split by Python

Tags: python, regex, csv

```
def csv_split() :
    raw = [ 
            '"1,2,3" , "4,5,6" , "456,789"',
            '"text":"a,b,c,d", "gate":"456,789"'
          ]
    cr = csv.reader( raw, skipinitialspace=True )
    for l in cr :
        print len( l ), l
```

This function outputs following:

```
3 ['1,2,3 ', '4,5,6 ', '456,789']
6 ['text:"a', 'b', 'c', 'd"', 'gate:"456', '789"']
```

As you can tell, the first line is correctly split into 3 entries.
But the second line is NOT. I would expect the csv reader splits it
into two, instead we've got 6 here. I have also thought about regex
approaches, but it assumes some specific quoting dialect.

Basically what I want is:
just split the string whenever there is a "," that is not quoted in a pair
of "".

Is there any quick and general way to do this? I have seen some regex hacks which
assumes that every filed is ALWAYS quoted etc. I think I can write a small loop
that does this very inefficiently, but would definitely appreciate some more
expertly advice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's splitting it correctly. Your CSV data is formatted wrongly. How do you think it _should_ be split?

Comment: You should say what you actually want for the second line, because I can't figure out what you're asking for.

Comment: @Gabe I think OP expected `'"text":"a,b,c,d"` and  `"gate":"456,789"'` -- OP please correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: @Levon: That would imply that he expects quotes to *sometimes* be stripped off and not other times. I'm having trouble figuring out a rule for that behavior.

Comment: @Gabe Agreed, it's a bit odd, only OP can clarify .. I think gnibbler is right, the data was formatted with an error.

Comment: If you want to parse JSON text, use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 2):

CSV isn't a standardized format, but it's common to escape quotation marks by using two `""` if they appear inside the text (e.g. `"text"":""a,b,c,d"`). Python's CSV reader is doing the right thing here, because it assumes this convention. I'm not quite sure what do you expect as output, but here is my try for a very simple CSV reader which might suit your format. Feel free to adapt it accordingly.

```
raw = [
    '"1,2,3" , "4,5,6" , "456,789"',
    '"text":"a,b,c,d", "gate":"456,789"',
    '1,2,  3,'
]

for line in raw:
    i, quoted, row = 0, False, []
    for j, c in enumerate(line):
        if c == ',' and not quoted:
            row.append(line[i:j].strip())
            i = j + 1
        elif c == '"':
            quoted = not quoted
    row.append(line[i:j+1].strip())
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if len(row[i]) >= 2 and row[i][0] == '"' and row[i][-1] == '"':
            row[i] = row[i][1:-1] # remove quotation marks
    print row
```

Output:

```
['1,2,3', '4,5,6', '456,789']
['text":"a,b,c,d', 'gate":"456,789']
['1', '2', '3', '']
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But yes, what I want is mentioned above:

'"text":"a,b,c,d", "gate":"456,789"' 

should be split into two entries:

[ '"text":"a,b,c,d"' , '"gate":"456,789"' ].


Like I said, I just want to split when the comma is not quoted.
I agree the CSV format is a bit messed up. But you know I can not control
what I am given sometimes. :(

Thanks for the great answers. I will try them out and see how to best resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here for posterity, because I struggled with this for a bit too.

The `quotechar` argument to `csv.reader()` helps resolve this; it'll let you ignore delims (i.e. commas, in this scenario) if they're inside quotes (assuming that all commas inside entries have been quoted). That is, it'll work for this:

```
Name, Message
Ford Prefect, Imagine this fork as the temporal universe.
Arthur Dent, "Hey, I was using that!"
```

...where the comma has been nested inside quotes, but the non-comma'd string has not.

Demo code ripped from the [Py2 docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader), and edited so that `delimiter` is a comma (duh) and `quotechar` is your double-quote `"`:

```py
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in spamreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```