# Python CSV Reader splitting on comma inside of quotes

Tags: python, csv

```
 from csv import reader

 csv_reader_results = reader(["办公室弥漫着\"女红\"缝扣子.编蝴蝶结..手绣花...呵呵..原来做 些也会有幸福的感觉,,,,用心做东西感觉真好!!!"],
 escapechar='\\',
 quotechar='"',
 delimiter=',',
 quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
 skipinitialspace=True)

 for result in csv_reader_result:
    print result[0]
```

What I'm expecting is:

> 办公室弥漫着"女红"缝扣子.编蝴蝶结..手绣花...呵呵..原来做  些也会有幸福的感觉,,,,用心做东西感觉真好!!!

But what I'm getting is:

> 办公室弥漫着"女红"缝扣子.编蝴蝶结..手绣花...呵呵..原来做  些也会有幸福的感觉

Because it splits on the four commas inside the sentence.

I'm escaping the quotes inside of the sentence. I've set the `quotechar` and `escapechar` for csv.reader. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

I used the answer by j6m8 https://stackoverflow.com/a/19881343/3945463 as a workaround. But it would be preferable to learn the correct way to do this with `csv reader.`

Comment: Use say it is splitting on a comma inside of quotes, but there is both a start and end quote before the first comma, as such what you are getting is correct.

Comment: Well there's one start quote, and two escaped quotes after that. So they shouldn't be counted as quotes really.

Comment: The start quote ie the first character is not part of the text.

Comment: If I had results = reader(["string one \" \",,,," , "string 2"]) it should return `string one "",,,,` and `string 2`. It should not be splitting on commas that are inside the quotations. But it does.